# How to iterate through JavaRDD and return a HashMap?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I want to create a HashMap for hive's "show table extended" output.I am trying below approach

```
   JavaRDD<HashMap<String,String>> hiveOutput = hiveContext.sql("show table extended like sourcing_trg_tbl").toJavaRDD().map(new Function<String,  Map<String,String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public  Map<String,String> call(String row) throws Exception {
                        return splitStringToMap(row);
                    }

                    private  Map<String,String> splitStringToMap(String s) {
                        String[] fields = s.toString().split(Pattern.quote(":"), -1);
                        Map<String,String> hiveMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        hiveMap.put(fields[0], fields[1]);
                        return hiveMap;
                    }
                });

                Map<String,String> hiveOutputMap = hiveOutput.collect();
```

While .map I am getting below error:

```
The method map(Function<Row,R>) in the type AbstractJavaRDDLike<Row,JavaRDD<Row>> is not applicable for the arguments (new Function<String,Map<String,String>>(){})
```

Is it not possible to return a Java Map through this approch?